# Asynchronous call in if statement ends up executing else statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

In specific case where we execute asynchronous call inside the `if` block, how come the `else` statement block gets executed if `doSubmit` evaluates to `true`? Outcome of this is that it always ends up at line after the `ERROR_2` comment:

```
$scope.save = function() {
    if (doSubmit) {
        var dto = {
            'attributes': $scope.fields,
            'requestOrigin': $location.absUrl()
        };
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'endpoint',
            data: dto
        };
        $http(req).success(function(data, status) {
            // SUCCESS
            $scope.completed(data);
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            // ERROR_1
            $scope.validationFailed();
        });

    } else {
        // ERROR_2
        $scope.validationFailed();
    }
}
// Used to provide error messages about input validation
$scope.validationFailed = function(message, id) {
    $scope.alerts.push({ 
        type: 'danger', 
        msg: message || 'error.validation_failed', id: id || 'general'
    });
}
```

I read about this case somewhere but can't remember the source. Any link or short elaboration would be helpful.

**ADDITION 1**
$scope.validationFailed

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: How do you know that `doSubmit === true` ??? as `if ( doSubmit ) { } else { }` will always execute the first block if true. Oh forgot.. The success and error functions will run after you have exited the current call stack so will not effect that conditional statement.

Comment: @Blindman67 inspected it of course, consider it hardcoded

Comment: Is doSubmit a variable or a function? The obvious answer is that doSubmit does not evaluate to true, even if you think it is doing so. The code inside the if statement cannot affect the if statement itself.

Comment: @HeadCode It is a variable, inspected it so many times...repeated the scenario where it ends up evaluating to true

Comment: @ IOlander OK, two more questions. What happens when you replace 'doSubmit' with 'true'? What happens when you comment out the code inside the if block?

Comment: @Juhana  I don't think so. In the case of the if block running, the outcome would not be $scope.outcome === 'ERROR_2', it would be $scope.outcome === undefined.

Comment: @HeadCode Good one, when i hardcode `doSubmit` to `true` it's the same, skips breakpoints on `ERROR_1` and ends on breakpoint at line with `ERROR_2`. However when i comment out the code in if statement and leave only a line with `SUCCESS` it holds there as expected.

Comment: So if you add `var doSubmit = true;` just before the code does it work? The only reason that it would act strangely is if you are calling the code with the condition elsewhere?

Comment: @Blindman67 Do submit is true and no it doesn't, still ends up in else block. Only when i remove async part and leave just SUCCESS line as is - then it stays in the if block.

Comment: For me, the strangest part is why does it end up in the else block. There is not a single scenario in my head to explain that.

Comment: All you are left with is to step through the code and see it happen. And just to ease my A.D.D. put a semicolon after you declare `var req =  {...};`  We need to see all the code around the code snippet you gave to work out what is going on as there is other stuff happening that we can not see.

Comment: @IOlander  Just to be clear, I was suggesting putting the reserved word 'true' inside the parentheses where you currently have doSubmit. That is the only way you can really test whether or not something else is messing with the doSubmit variable.

Comment: @Blinman67 Searched all the occurrences of the `save` function which surround this code, nothing else than `ngClick` event bind on a button. Will try to replicate the scenario with a mock logic and show it using jsfiddle. I did exactly that, `if (true) {` I'll even put that in a comment above the line of code.

Comment: @IOlander  Ah, OK. Well, this is the most bizarre thing I'm probably going to see all week....

Comment: @HeadCode Probably most bizarre thing i did ever, stay tuned to find out the stupid cause

Comment: @IOlander  I have to at least guess one last time. Were you presetting $scope.outcome = 'ERROR_2' somewhere ahead of this code?

Comment: @HeadCode Well i just realized that there are some thing that i've hidden and it was totally unneeded, will update the question now

Comment: Maybe it's the `$http` **error** callback from where `$scope.validationFailed();` is executed? Try adding `alert(1);` in your error callback

Comment: @Alon Bingo, can you elaborate in answer why didn't it break on the line of that error?

Answer (score 1):

My comment as an answer:

Maybe it's the `$http` **error** callback from where `$scope.validationFailed();` is executed? Try adding `alert(1);` in your error callback.

This might indicate a server side problem, causing the server return status code different from **200** Both your `else` statement and the error callback are eventually executing the same function, but it just show that the else statement is NOT the one being executed.

Comment: Strange thing for me is that the execution didn't stop on the breakpoint of that specific call of `validationFailed()` function, but the later one in an `else` block. Great idea with that `alert()`